How to ignore tables of a name pattern in SSDT deployments?
In SSDT, I know I can ignore any predefined script by setting its "build action" property to "None".
What about tables I don't know the exact name but following a particular pattern, like '%backup%' for instance?
Is there a way to create "exclude patterns" in SSDT?
If not, could I exclude ALL objects in a particular schema?
What I am trying to do is to ignore backup tables created by our code.
So far, we identify them by a name pattern.
I guess we could create them in a specific schema.
If even this is not possible... Maybe we could create them into another database I guess...

The only way of achieving that is to use custom deployment contributor. It's not so hard or complex, however it will be some custom code. https://the.agilesql.club/ author used to post articles on how to do that, however it was long time ago and I'm not sure if he is still writing anything about SSDT
